# Proving that a function is monotone

Tags: probability-distributions, economics

Here is the setting: We have a middleman that buys a product from the producers, and sells the product to the customers. The middleman charges a price $R$ to the customers, and pays a price $p(R)$ to buy the product from the producers.

We use $G(R)$ to denote a cumulative density function for a probability distribution, with $G(0)=0$ and $G(\infty)=1$. The $1-G(x)$ distribution represents the customer's willingness to pay for a product, and it is the fraction of consumer that will buy the product if it is priced at $R$.

We know (from other analysis) that the optimal price to pay to the producers of the product $p(R) = R-\frac{1-G(R)}{G'(R)}$. (Assume that the middleman is a monopsonist with the power to set the price of buying.)

Assuming that we are interested only in regions where $p(R)<R$ (i.e., we make a profit when selling) and $p(R)>0$ (i.e., we need to pay a non-zero price to procur the product from the producer), can we prove that the function $p(R)$ does not decrease when we increase the price $R$? In other words, if we increase the price R that we charge customers, can we show that the price that we are willing to pay the supplier also increases?

By setting $\frac{d}{dR}p(R) \geq 0$ we get $G''(R) \geq -2 \cdot \frac{\left(G'(R)\right)^2}{1-G(R)}$

Can we prove that the latter holds, assuming that G(R) can be an arbitrary probability distribution with support in $(0..\infty)$ and that we only care for the regions where $p(R)<R$ and $p(R)>0$? Assume that G'(R) and G''(R) exist, that they are continuous, differentiable, etc.

Comment: So wait, the higher my price, the more likely I am to buy it?

Comment: For an arbitrary probability distribution, we don't even have that $G'$ and $G''$ exist.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, the iPhone effect :) Then again, if we exchang ecause and effect(?) The more people demand a limited product, the higher the price

Comment: Also, this text is bit confusing: "... the optimal price to pay for procuring the product to sell." Procuring usually means "buying" or at least getting into your hands. So "for procuring the product to sell" only makes sense if what you mean is that you are buying the product with the intent of selling it immediately. That seems unlikely to be what you mean, but I can't find another meaning for that bit.

Comment: I made some edits to the description for clarifying the setting. Hope that the new wording helps. @HagenvonEitzen let's work for now with the assumption that G is arbitrary but is continuous and differentiable, (and same for G', G'', etc)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry, mea culpa. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems that I managed to solve this.

Taking the derivative of p(R) and by setting it to be greater than or equal to 0, we have:

$G′′(R)⋅(1−G(R))≥−2⋅G′(R)⋅G′(R)$

Taking the integral of both sides:

$∫G′′(R)−∫G′′(R)⋅G(R)≥−2∫G′(R)⋅G′(R)$

Taking integration by parts for $∫G′′(R)⋅G(R)$ we have:

$G′(R)−G(R)⋅G′(R)≥−3∫G′(R)⋅G′(R)$

Taking the integral of both sides again:

$G(R)−∫G(R)⋅G′(R)≥−3∫∫G′(R)⋅G′(R)$

We have that ∫G(R)⋅G′(R)=12G(R)2 and this results in:

$G(R)(1−\frac{1}{2}G(R))+3∫∫G′(R)⋅G′(R)≥0$

Since $G(R)≥0$, $1−\frac{1}{2}G(R)≥0.5$ and $G′(R)≥0$, we have a sum of positive terms, which is positive. QED

Answer (score 1):

So in general I know that this does not hold, because your expression is exactly the myerson virtual value, and there is a long literature about suitable regularity conditions to make it increasing. If you assume log-concavity of your distribution for example then you are done. But this is too strong in that you can actually assume -.5 concavity. I refer you to optimal design and $\rho$-concavity.

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?
doi=10.1.1.362.7589&rep=rep1&type=pdf